# Accessing Roles from Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, roles

I am creating my own custom authorize attribute, overriding the AuthorizeCore method and wanted to know if it is possible to access the Roles which have been passed into the authorize attribute tag.

So for instance if I have this:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Administrator, Sales, Entry")]
```

Is it possible to access these from inside here:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
    }
```

I could then split the string and create an array.

Comment: look at here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9479442/745331

Answer (score 9):

You can this `this.Roles` which is a string that you need to split.

The source code is freely available.

The default AuthorizeCore implementation:

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    if (httpContext == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
    }

    IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        return false;
    }

    if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And they have an internal split function which looks like this:

```
internal static string[] SplitString(string original) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original)) {
        return new string[0];
    }

    var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                select trimmed;
    return split.ToArray();
}
```